# How to get to know which GPU the machine uses?

Tags: gpu, cpu, processor, amd-processor

I have an unknown Linux machine, I need to check which GPU it uses (more specifically if it uses an AMD GPU). To know more about CPUs I have used `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Is there something similar for GPUs?

Answer (score 0):

If `clinfo` is available, it'll give you a list of OpenCL-capable compute devices, including GPUs. You're out of luck if GPUs are not supporting OpenCL or drivers are not installed. There is no generic way of getting a list of all kinds of GPU devices. On some platforms you can at least get a list of discrete GPUs from `lspci` output, but you'll miss the integrated and non-PCI GPUs this way.

If you already have an X11 server running on that box, you can always do `glxinfo` on it. It cannot be done in a headless way though.